# 6502 How to get instruction from opcode

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, 6502

how can i get know what instruction is behind binary opcode ?

For example : 
0010000000000111

I was trying to convert it to hex - 2007 and find it on http://www.masswerk.at/6502/6502_instruction_set.html but it doesn`t work.
Any ideas ?

EDIT:

00100000 00000111 -> JSR 07

10010000 00001011 -> BCC 0B

00110000 00001001 -> BMI 09

Is this correct ?

Comment: 6502 is a 8 bit processor. Having 16 bit like that is very unusual, make sure you know how it's meant to be interpreted. `20 07` would be a `JSR` but that is a 3 byte instruction so you don't have enough data.

Comment: for 6502, instructions are always one byte. What follows are the operands. So: lookup the instruction byte in your opcode table, and find how many (0..2) operand bytes you should expect for this instruction.

Comment: variable length instruction sets you cant just jump in the middle you have to disassemble in execution order starting at an entry point (reset or an interrupt) and go from there.  Is that what you are doing here?  jumping into the middle of some bytes or at an entry point?

Comment: This is one of exercies on my studies

Comment: You can check your work with an on-line diassembler: http://www.e-tradition.net/bytes/6502/disassembler.html For example, `20 07 00` disassembles to `JSR $0007`

Comment: _"JSR 07"_ The operand for `JSR` is always two bytes.

Comment: The second two of your three examples are correct. The first one is not because `JSR`  opcode number `$20` uses absolute addressing, so there are two bytes following the opcode to specify where the processor jumps to.

Answer (score 2):

1. Better use hexadecimal numbers, not binary. Each hexadecimal digit is exactly 4 bits, so your 00100000 becomes $20, which is immediately recognized as JSR opcode (well, immediately for me, of course :)
2. Read some introductory 6502 manuals, like these ones: http://6502.org/tutorials/. For your specific need try [this page](http://6502.org/tutorials/6502opcodes.html) or first table [from here](http://www.oxyron.de/html/opcodes02.html), that will be especially useful once you'll get an idea of total command length (1, 2 or 3 bytes) from the introductory course.